# Необработанное исключение типа "System.AccessViolationException" в mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

Возвращаясь к проблеме данного кода [Глобальный хук клавиш](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914900/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88). Оказалось он работает, НО только при установке Цели платформы х32. Моя программа разработана для x64 систем.

При попытке нажатия определенной клавиши возникает следующая ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.AccessViolationException" в mscorlib.dll
>   Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена.

На строку:

```
Int32 vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32((IntPtr)L);
```

Как это можно исправить (используя онли x64)?

Comment: Для меня вопрос исчерпан в связи с переходом на х86. Появилась возможность.

Comment: Int32 имеет разный размер для сборок 32/64. Маршалинг теоретически должен это учитывать, но вероятно не в вашем случае.. посмотрите API чего вы там unmanaget вызываете, и его параметры для 64 бит версии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размер указателей в x64 не совпадает с размером типа int. Если вы используете для представления указателей тип int, он будет работать только в x86. Правильное объявление  Low-Level Keyboard Hook callback должно выглядеть так:

```
IntPtr KeyboardHookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
```

Тип IntPtr соответствует размерности указателя текущей платформы. Вообще, полный рабочий пример кода с Low-Level Keyboard Hook приведен здесь: [Как отловить все клавиши через низкоуровневый хук?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879772/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA)