# Как установить низкоуровневый хук на отдельный процесс?

Tags: c#

Как установить хук на один процесс?

```
private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
private static Form1 _applicationForm;


// Данный метод устанавливает хук на все процессы:
private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
{
   using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
   using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
   {
      return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
      GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
   }
}

private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{ 
   return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Как мне установить только на отдельный процесс?

Comment: Последний параметр `SetWindowsHookEx` принимает PID процесса.

Comment: Low-level хуки не требуют выноса в отдельную библиотеку. Можете устанавливать их прямо в своём приложении и в 3ий параметр передавать `NULL`.

Comment: @D.Stark, В каком смысле отдельную библиотеку? Так значит можно установить только через PID, я думал можно через список процессов как-то пройтись найти нужный и установить только на нужный процесс хук.

Comment: "_В каком смысле отдельную библиотеку?_" - Иначе зачем вы передаёте дескриптор модуля в функцию? Почитайте документацию.

Comment: @D.Stark, Я так и не понял про какую документацию вы говорите?! Что не так с кодом? Если можно дайте прямой ответ что не так.

Comment: "_Так значит можно установить только через PID_" - А как вам ещё надо? Что мешает выполнить поиск нужного процесса по имени и запомнить его id?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa

Comment: @D.Stark, `"Что мешает выполнить поиск нужного процесса по имени и запомнить его id?"` Как это сделать?

Comment: Где вы размещаете свой код? В библиотеке или в приложении?

Comment: @D.Stark, В приложение (console)

Comment: "_Как это сделать?_" - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/psapi/enumerating-all-processes

Comment: @D.Stark, Там же на С++, а мне на шарпе нужно.

Comment: "_В приложение (console)_" - В консоли хуки работать не будут. Приложение должно быть оконным. В 3ий параметр `SetWindowsHookEx` вы должны передать `NULL`, так как он предназначен для дескриптора библиотеки, а ваш код размещается в приложении.

Comment: "_Там же на С++, а мне на шарпе нужно_" - Про хуки говорим, на уме C++)) Тогда всё намного проще: `Process.GetProcessByName`.

Comment: @D.Stark, почему в консольном не будет? Вроде бы должно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможности установить низкоуровневый хук на отдельный процесс нет. Низкоуровневый хук потому и назван "низкоуровневым", что он вызывается до того, как событие ввода доходит до целевого процесса (точнее потока, так как очереди сообщений принадлежат потокам). Несмотря на то, что функция SetWindowsHookEx позволяет передать четвертым параметром ID потока для установки хука только на события этого потока, для WH_KEYBOARD_LL этот параметр не работает, похоже, именно из-за его особой природы.

Однако, в какой именно процесс будет отправлено сообщение, в общем, не секрет: это процесс, владеющий текущим активным окном. Это значит, что реализовать фильтрацию событий хука определенного процесса можно довольно просто с использованием функций GetWindowThreadProcessId и GetForegroundWindow. Переработав пример [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/880287/240512), получаем такой код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] prs = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            if (prs.Length == 0) throw new ApplicationException("Process not found!");
            KeyLogger.SetHook((uint)prs[0].Id);
        }
    }

    class KeyLogger
    {
        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        const int HC_ACTION = 0;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        const uint VK_CAPITAL = 0x14;        
        static uint hookProcessID;
        static IntPtr hookID;
        static KeyboardProc Callback = KeyboardHookCallback;


        public static void SetHook(uint pid)
        {
            hookProcessID = pid;
            hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, Callback, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            if (hookID == IntPtr.Zero) throw new ApplicationException("Failed to install hook!");
            Console.WriteLine("Started listening keyboard events...");
            Application.Run();
        }               

        static IntPtr KeyboardHookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                uint pid = 0;
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), out pid);

                if (pid == hookProcessID)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Key: " + ((Keys)vkCode).ToString() + ";");
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        delegate IntPtr KeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, KeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint ProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();   
    }    
}
```

Comment: Разве при установке хука приложение может быть консольным? Должен же быть цикл обработки сообщений.

Comment: @D.Stark Он есть - `Application.Run();`. Консольные приложения тоже могут иметь цикл обработки сообщений (у меня для этого добавлена ссылка на System.Windows.Forms, но можно, конечно, обойтись и без этого)

Comment: Т.е. фишка в добавлении ссылки на System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: @D.Stark нет, сама по себе ссылка ничего не решает. Фишка, в том, что вы сказали - в цикле обработки сообщений. Просто он может быть запущен по разному, либо вызовом Application.Run из Windows Forms (или WPF), либо явными вызовами GetMessage - TranslateMessage - DispatchMessage. Тип проекта же здесь не имеет особого значения.