# Для чего нужны делегаты в C#?

Tags: c#, делегаты

Разбираюсь в c# в частности с делегатами, возник вопрос зачем нужны делегаты если можно создать экземпляр класса и вызвать метод.

Экземпляр класса

```
class MainClass
{
    public string  Print3(string s)
    {
        return s + "hello bro";
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        MainClass m = new MainClass();
        m.Print3...
    }
}
```

Делегат

```
delegate string Print2(string s);
class MainClass
{
    static string  Print3(string s)
    {
        return s + "hello bro";
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Print2 p = new Print2(Print3);
        string s = p("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: А теперь передайте этот метод другому классу и пусть он его вызовет. А еще лучше, если другой класс принимает для вызова не один метод, а коллекцию методов.

Comment: Делегат можно передавать в функции и добавлять обработчиком события.

Comment: @tym32167 создаю экземпляр класса MainClass и передаю метод

Comment: `var obstacles = c.FindObstacles (v).Where (o => !o.Entity.PassableFor (this) && !Excluded.Contains (o.Entity));` для каждого такого случая создавать целый метод? И как в этот метод закинуть контекст вызова?

Comment: не совсем понятно можно пожалуйста более доступным языком?)полегче пример

Comment: Покажите это кодом

Comment: `class Nvm
    {
        public void Start()
        {
            MainClass m2 = new MainClass();
            string ms = m2.Print3("s");
            Console.WriteLine(ms);
            

            

        }
    }`

Comment: где тут передача метода через параметр? `другой класс принимает для вызова не один метод, а коллекцию методов`?

Comment: Интерфейсы описывают контракт класса и позволяют передать экземляр **любого** класса, лишь бы он реализовывал интерфейс. Делегаты - такое же описание но для методов (сигнатура) и позволяют передавать как параметр **любой** метод, лишь бы сигнатура подходила. И интерфейс и делегат определяют лишь сигнатуру чтобы не завязываться на конкретные MainClass и Print3. Привычный пример - вызов чего-то и передача каллбека. Вызываемый метод знать не знает про ваши MainClass.Print3 потому и просит "дай мне любой метод лишь бы он был сигнатурой калбека"

Comment: @vitidev ну, строго говоря, не только для того, чтобы передать как параметр, но, и, например, для реализации событий )

Comment: а зачем передавать как параметр?

Comment: ну, например 1) Передать какую то работу в [пул потоков](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem?view=netframework-4.8) или [таск](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8) 2) Передать какой то вызов функции контексту синзронизации или [диспетчеру](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=netframework-4.8) 3) Банально иметь возможность сопоставить что то с каким то действием 4) ещё миллион сценариев

Comment: А можете прояснить про  Ковариантность и контравариантность если не сложно

Comment: Всю тему что ли пояснить? [раз](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.28.php), [два](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.27.php), [три](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), [четыре](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level11/11_14.php)  - если после этого всё ещё не понятно, то задавайте отдельный вопрос с указанием конкретно непонятных вещей, что вы не понимаете, с примерами вашего кода как попыток разобраться самому.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Вопрос:** Можно ли обойтись без делегатов?

**Ответ:** Да. Java, можно сказать, обходится без них, до версии 8 так и аналогов никаких не было. Да и во многих других языках аналогов нет.

**Вопрос:** Можно ли код, который использует делегаты, переписать без делегатов?

**Ответ:** Да. Например, в той же Java, до версии 8, всегда когда нужно было привязать слушатель к событию нужно было объявить класс. Выглядело это примерно так:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clickevent) {
        System.out.println("Button Clicked");
  }
});
```

**Вопрос:** Для чего нужны делегаты?

**Ответ:** Это [синтаксический сахар](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80). Они позволяют писать код короче.

Например, аналог кода выше на C#:

```
button.Click += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Button clicked");
```

Делегаты тесно связаны с другими элементами языка:

- на них реализованы операторы [сложения и вычитания](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/how-to-combine-delegates-multicast-delegates);
- они работают с методами, анонимными методами и лямбда-выражениями;
- привязываются к событиям.

Все это можно при желании реализовать самому через классы и интерфейсы, но этот функционал расширяет возможности языка, позволяет писать более короткий код.

Если можете написать код без делегатов — пишите. Но если тот же код можно написать быстрее и проще с делегатами было бы странно их не использовать.

Вообще, без большей части функционала языка можно обойтись: код, в котором используется наследование, можно переписать без него; классы можно переписать на процедурах и т.д. Любой код на C# можно переписать на ассемблере без потери производительности и функционала. Просто кода будет намного больше. В [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) всего 8 инструкций и любой код на C# теоретически можно переписать на нем. Разница в производительности если будет, то она скорее будет связана с поддержкой оптимизаций на уровне ОС и процессоров чем с возможностями языка.

P.S. Последний раз про Java: в версии 8 ввели лямбда-выражения не вводя при этом понятия «делегат» и «событие» на уровне языка. Вместо делегатов используются интерфейсы. Из-за отстутствия поддержки на уровне языка операторы на них не определены и объявление выглядит чуть более громоздко, но возможности те же.

Answer (score 4):

Один из примеров, когда без делегатов вовсе не обойтись - взаимодействие с кодом на процедурных языках программирования, который оперирует указателями на функции. Например, см. [данный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/880287/240512), в котором определяется делегат

```
delegate IntPtr KeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

который передается в неуправляемую функцию [SetWindowsHookEx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) в качестве параметра HOOKPROC. Исключительно на классах (через шаблон "Наблюдатель") это не реализовать.

Comment: Хороший пример, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

С помощью делегатов можно передать ссылку на метод или сам метод как параметр.

Например:

```
User GetUser(uint id, Action<Exception> onError)
```

Этот метод возвращает объект User, и если произошла ошибка то выполняет НАШ код передавая в него Exception

```
try {} catch(Exception e) {
OnError?.Invoke(e);
}
```

Конкретно в Вашем случае можно не создавать новый делегат, а воспользоваться встроенным Action.

```
void Print(Action<string> print2) {
    print2?.Invoke("myMessage");
}
```

Вызвать такой метод можно следующим образом:

```
void Print2((e) => { Console.WriteLn(e); }
```